# Automatically create multiple classes each of which matches one from external library

Tags: c#, class

Let's say we have this external code we cannot modify:

```
public class Foo1 : Foo
{
    public object A1 { get; set; }
    public object B1 { get; set; }
    public object C1 { get; set; }
    public object D1 { get; set; }
    public Foo1() { }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public object A2 { get; set; }
    public object B2 { get; set; }
    public object C2 { get; set; }
    public object D2 { get; set; }
    public Foo2() { }
}

public class FooN : Foo
{
    public object AN { get; set; }
    public object BN { get; set; }
    public object CN { get; set; }
    public object DN { get; set; }
    public FooN() { }
}
```

A list of classes that have some properties - not always the same.

Is there a way in c# framework to create multiple objects - as much as the count of the classes above - that:
 1. Have got the Foo# classes as property;
 2. Have got some more properties

I am thinking at something like this:

```
public class Bar1
{
    public Foo1 Value { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar2
{
    public Foo2 Value { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class BarN
{
    public FooN Value { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

"Child" properties would be constant in this case.

I cannot create an abstract class or an interface that does that.
I understand that this probably is a bad way to go.

Comment: It's not something I've had much of a chance to experiment with but T4 templates might be of use?

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit your exact situation, but it might fit the general situation you've described...

You could use generics.

```
public class Bar<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Bar(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

var wrappedFoo1 = Bar<Foo1>(new Foo1());
var wrappedFoo2 = Bar<Foo2>(new Foo2());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, you can do something like that;

Firstly, create a `BarBase` class like this;

```
public class BarBase
{
    private string _derivedClassName;

    public Foo Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_derivedClassName))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var fooType = typeof(Foo).Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Foo" + _derivedClassName.Substring(_derivedClassName.Length - 1, 1));
            if (fooType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Activator.CreateInstance(fooType) as Foo;
        }
    }

    public BarBase(string derivedClassName)
    {
        _derivedClassName = derivedClassName;
    }
}
```

And then you can change `Bar1` class like this;

```
public class Bar1 : BarBase
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Bar1() : base("Bar1")
    {

    }
}
```

Usage;

```
    var bar = new Bar1();
    var foo1 = (Foo1)bar.Value;
```

Thus, you can create unlimited `Bar` classes and their `Foo` instances dynamically.